# How to make Flash autoplay using <embed> tag?

Tags: html, flash

When I use `<embed>` tags like this:

```
<embed src="flashfile.swf" autostart="true"></embed>
```

It may not autoplay.

But if I user other fromat like this:

```
<embed src="flashfile.wmv" autostart="true"></embed>
```

It will work well. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the autostart attribute is something the flash object interprets.  The embed tag doesn't have any specification for how the object being embedded handles any attributes or parameters passed, as it's completely up to the discretion of the vendor creating the object.  So, essentially, the wmv embed listens for an attribute called autostart, and a swf does not.

Flash embeds actually do automatically start, but if there's some ActionScript that stops the animation or whatever else that is happening, there's not much you can do.  If the swf object has an external interface enabled, you can interact with the object with JavaScript.  Other than that, there's nothing else you can do.

I hope this provides some insight!

Comment: So the key is docuemnt,rather than the attribute of the tags